# How to move glyphicon to float right?

Tags: html, css

I have a search textbox.

Like this:

```css
.entypo-search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0px;
}

li.lien-he-padding{
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.form-search {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}


form {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  margin-top: -5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.entypo-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}

.form-search:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b3cccc;
  width: 230px;
}

.form-search:hover form input {
  width: 200px;
}

.form-search form input:focus, 
.form-search form input:active{
  outline:none;
  width: 300px;
}

li div.form-search:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
  <div class="form-search">
    <form action="#" class="entypo-search glyphicon glyphicon-search">
      <fieldset><input id="search" placeholder="Search" /></fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

This working with me. But I want the `glyphicon glyphicon-search` float to the right of the text box.

I tried to add from:

```
<form action="#" class="entypo-search glyphicon glyphicon-search">
```

to:

```
<form action="#" class="entypo-search glyphicon glyphicon-search icon-arrow-right pull-right">
```

But can't apply to `form` element.

So, I tried to wrap form with  element.

But you can see: seem position of  is hidden.

```css
.entypo-search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0px;
}

.form-search {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}


form {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  margin-top: -5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.entypo-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}

.form-search:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b3cccc;
  width: 230px;
}

.form-search:hover form input {
  width: 200px;
}

.form-search form input:focus, 
.form-search form input:active{
  outline:none;
  width: 300px;
}

li div.form-search:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
  <div class="form-search">
    <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon-arrow-right pull-right">
      <form action="#" class="entypo-search">
        <fieldset><input id="search" placeholder="Search" /></fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you please post a live example reproducing the problem?

Comment: You can see at here: http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/BLBNOE

Comment: So when I search, you want the magnifying glass glyph on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.entypo-search` style is overridden by `.glyphicon` and therefore you need to add `!important` to the style. Also the `right: 0` has to be set for `.entypo-search:before` instead of the `left` property.

Checkout the codepen link http://codepen.io/jarun/pen/Zpzbwo

```css
.entypo-search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  right: 0px;
}

li.lien-he-padding{
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.form-search {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}


form {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  margin-top: -5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.entypo-search {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 30% !important;
  right: 0;
}

.form-search:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b3cccc;
  width: 230px;
}

.form-search:hover form input {
  width: 200px;
}

.form-search form input:focus, 
.form-search form input:active{
  outline:none;
  width: 300px;
}

li div.form-search:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
  <div class="form-search">
    <form action="#" class="entypo-search glyphicon glyphicon-search">
      <fieldset><input id="search" placeholder="Search" /></fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You should increment property `right` in `.entypo-search` about 10px to easy look. Thank you very much. You answer resolve my question.

Comment: Thanks @z0mBi. Good luck a day.

Comment: I have a small problem. Is: when typing in this text box, I want a width of this input is limit like an image. And seem space between two letter is big. I tried to add: `letter-spacing: normal` but it not works. http://i.imgur.com/v0LYe8j.png

Comment: You need to use `!important` to set the width of input box. `#form:hover form input {  width: 180px !important; }`. I have updated my codepen

Comment: You see in real code. If change to width: 180px it will show like that: http://i.imgur.com/TQAyjyZ.png

Comment: In the codepen I have shared I dont see such issue. Can you share the updated code?

Comment: I fixed it. Decrease width of the input and add padding-left in the `formseach`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `has-feedback` and move the `glyphicon` to a `span` after the input. That's already done in Bootstrap, so you don't need any CSS for that.

```css
li.lien-he-padding {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.form-search {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}
form {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: none;
}
.entypo-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}
.form-search:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b3cccc;
  width: 230px;
}
.form-search:hover form input {
  width: 200px;
}
.form-search form input:focus,
.form-search form input:active {
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
}
li div.form-search:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<li>
  <div class="form-search">
    <form action="#" class="entypo-search has-feedback">
      <fieldset>
        <input id="search" placeholder="Search" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks @racil hilan